# notepad++ python replace with incremental number

Tags: python, notepad++

I have hopefully an easy question. I am very familiar with notepad++ and regex but am new to the python plugin for notepad++. I understand the plugin would have the capability to replace a value with a number then increase the number it is replaced with.

The code I want to change looks like the below:

```
    Hello, blah blah blah <a href="#filepos14613280" >@*</a> blah blah blah
    More stuff <a href="#filepos14634533" >@*</a> blah blah blah
    Even more stuff <a href="#filepos14614629" >@*</a> blah blah blah
```

And I want to change it to look like:

```
    Hello, blah blah blah <a href="#filepos14613280" >1</a> blah blah blah
    More stuff <a href="#filepos14634533" >2</a> blah blah blah
    Even more stuff <a href="#filepos14614629" >3</a> blah blah blah
```

Any help as to what the .py file/script should look like would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this a python question?

Comment: you could probably make your own program that writes this to a file easier

Comment: It is a python question since it uses the python plugin in notepad++.

Comment: What program would I used to write this to a file?

Answer (score 1):

a simple example of this program you might want to write to change the one spot of the lines is below:

```
lines = open('filename.whatever').readlines()
NewLines = []
increments = 1

for line in lines:
    NewLines.append(line.replace('@*', str(increments)))
    increments += 1

with open('filename_modified.whatever', 'w') as new:
    new.write('\n'.join(NewLines))
```

but, of course, replace 'filename.whatever' with whatever the filename is.
hope this works! (this is not really notepad++ related, but i think it is your best option.)

Comment: your question is slightly unclear, so if this is not what you wanted, tell me

Answer (score 1):

I hope the two functions below will help you :)

**First function**

```
    # replace multiple occurrences of a string by an incremental number
    # e.g.      <rn>, <rn>, <rn> ...
    #                becomes
    #           <rn1>, <rn2>, <rn3> ...
    #
    # **m.group(1)** same like regex argument **\1**
    # **global counter** means: use (global) variable **counter** outside def in def
    # more about global and local variables: https://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php


    import re

    counter = 0

    def get_counter(m):
        global counter
        counter = counter + 1
        return m.group(1) + str(counter) + '>'

    editor.rereplace('(<rn)>', get_counter, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Second function**

```
    # replace X followed by numbers by an incremental number
    # e.g.   X56 X39 X999
    #          becomes
    #        Y57 Y40 Y1000

    def add_1(m):
        return 'Y' + str(int(m.group(1)) + 1)

    editor.rereplace('X([0-9]+)', add_1)
```